# Custom Shape for Flutter Slider track

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I need to change the Flutter slider ui to expecting (shared the image below) Style; is it possible?

```
Slider(
  value: _currentSliderValue,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  divisions: 100,
  onChanged: (double value) {
    setState(() {
      _currentSliderValue = value;
    });
  },
),
```

Expecting output
[image: the expected output design]

Comment: try with `transform: Matrix4.identity() ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.01)  ..rotateY((pi / 180) * 40)`

Comment: where.? can you explain it.?

Comment: Try checking `Transform` with that value, but it will provide touch issue, better use customPaint